# https://example.com redirects to a wrong url using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

so I'm having trouble with .htaccess file. This is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

it redirects first from non www to www, and then from non https to https but it has a problem, when going to:

```
https://example.com
```

i.e: with https but not www it redirects me to a huge link, something like:

```
https://www.example.com/home/c3238912/public_html/httpss://www.example.com/home/c3238912/public_html/httpss://www.example.com/home/c3238912/public_html/httpss://www.example.com/home/c3238912/public_html/
```

How can be this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Did you duplicate the `s` in your https redirect but forgot to mention it here?

Your example shows `httpss` in the redirected path. A typo like this would cause this issue as the `httpss` protocol doesn't exist, it's considered as a path, hence the infinite redirect.

My understanding is you real rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ httpss://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Remove the extra `s`, exactly like you show it in your question.
If you had a typo before, but corrected it, make sure you empty your cache. Redirects *are* cached.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it is running your second Redirect multiple times. Instead of having your rules split, you can connect them which should hopefully fix the multiple redirects.

Try using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

I've changed the `R` flag to 302, this makes it a temporary redirect for testing purposes. If you find this rule works, then change it back to 301 for a permanent redirect.

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.